# Percentage is either 0 or 100

Tags: c#

I'm failing to understand why this will only return 0 or 100.

```
decimal TotalUptimePercent;
TotalUptimePercent = (uptime / (uptime + downtime)) * 100;
MessageBox.Show("Uptime: " + TotalUptimePercent.ToString());
```

I've tried using double instead of decimal but that didn't work either.

I did look over the site and found some other posts about percentages which recommended using decimal, but isn't working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `uptime` and `downtime` are `int` or alike, try

```
double TotalUptimePercent = (uptime / (uptime + (double)downtime)) * 100;
```

See [/ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx):

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

Comment: i notice it doesn't matter which one you place the (double) on - just thought that was interesting

Comment: @AaronAnodide, it's the nature of operator overloading, if one of the operand is double, it will use double division / addition, and return the same type

Comment: @AaronAnodide In this particular case it does not matter, you can cast any `uptime`or `downtime` (but not `100`). But if we'd have something like `a/b/c`, it would matter. `a/(double)b/c` is not the same as `a/b/(double)c` .

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now.